# How to add label into form builder (not in twig)?

Tags: forms, symfony, fosuserbundle

I have this code, but it doesn't work:

```
$builder->add('name','text',array(
    'label'  => 'Due Date',
));
```

---

the problem i have in fosuserbundle, i have overring form

```
<?php
namespace Acme\UserBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilder;
use FOS\UserBundle\Form\Type\RegistrationFormType as BaseType;

class RegistrationFormType extends BaseType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
    {


        // add your custom field
        $builder->add('name','text',array(
    'label'  => 'Due Date',
));
        parent::buildForm($builder, $options);
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'acme_user_registration';
    }
}
```

but not work, not give me any error and set the label "fos_user_registration_form_name"

Comment: Your code looks correct. How do you verify that it doesn't work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You see label as `fos_user_registration_form_name`, because `FOSUserBundle` uses translations files to translate all texts in it.

You have to add your translations to file called like `Resources/translations/FOSUserBundle.nb.yml` (example for norwegian) or you can modify translations file coming with the bundle (copying it to `Acme\UserBundle` is a better way).

Comment: only i not understand how set the translation

Comment: Copy translation file from original bundle to your bundle into same location. Say, from `vendor/bundles/FOS/UserBundle/Resources/translations/FOSUserBundle.de.yml` to `src/Acme/UserBundle/Resources/translations/FOSUserBundle.de.yml`. And add label translation there.

Comment: i have copy (FOSUserBundle.it.yml)  but is english yet :(

Comment: i have also set in config.yml:
    translator: { fallback: it }
and parameter.ini:

Comment: Thanks this answered my question about this, just to clarify to anyone else you basically need to add an entry at the bottom of the translation file in the section marked '#form field labels' with the name of the field that is being displayed in the form, in this case `fos_user_registration_form_name: "Your name:"` should do the trick.